# Error on typings for toPromise and WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

WebStorm does not seem to be recognising the typings for the `toPromise` function on 'rxjs'. Is this anything I can fix? I have updated it.

However it does work when I run the code. Which is weird.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so got this working in the end. My process was

1. Delete npm globals folder @ 'usr/local/lib/node_modules'
2. Re-install node and npm
3. Delete all my local node_modules
4. npm cache clear
5. restart webstorm

Now it magically picked up the type def. I would say generally I just had to clear out as much as possible and get it all rebuild.